# How can I play sound with library Plugin.MediaManager (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

XAML

```
<Button Text="Play" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
```

C#

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3");
}
```

Nothing happens when I press the button (Xamarin LivePlayer, iOS)

lib: https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

Comment: Live Player is not intended to be a complete iOS emulator.  I'm not surprised this doesn't work in that environment.

Comment: thanks for answer @Jason